# Skype not starting on on x64 13.04

Tags: skype

Having this weird problem with starting up skype...
Already tried installing from the debian package, removing skype and reinstalling from debian package, reinstalling from the app market, reinstalling from repository, etc etc..
Still no success

```
    **ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD      cannot be preloaded: ignored.
    /usr/lib/skype/skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Any advice?

Tried the following 
`teemu@TeemuPC-715517:~$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1 skype
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libnvidia-tls.so.319.17: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` Yet no luck. :/

Comment: From what I can understand it needs the 32 bit version of that library.